# Make ClickOnce Full Trust application "green"

Tags: .net, clickonce, full-trust

I signed my clickonce manifests with a valid certificate from a trusted CA.
And I configured a "full trust" application (because I need access to the file system, the internet, etc.)

Now I get this popup when starting the application via clickonce:

[image]

As you see it is "green" in 3 out of 4 categories.

Is there a way to make my clickonce "green" in all 4 (but still keeping it as "full trust" application)?

Comment: Can you type a translation of the dialog boxes into your question?

Comment: This is the usual popup, what you get.

The red part of the window on the right side says: 

**Computer access: this application will get access to additional resources on your computer, e.g. the file system or network connections. This brings a potential risk. Only agree and proceed if you trust the publisher of the application.**